# Jquery - How to I add an event after dynamic create

Tags: jquery

I am creating a div dynamically, then appending it to a container:

```
var str = '<div class="dimsdiv" id="'+dim.src+'" cursor:pointer;"></div>'; 
$('#fpdiv').append(str);
```

Now I need to add a hover even to those divs. I tried to just reference it, but then found that I needed to consider .on() instead. I tried this (before on):

```
$('#'+dim.src).hover(function{},function{});
```

But as expected, that didn't work. I also tried this:

```
$('#'+dim.src).on('hover','(function{},function{})');
```

but can't seem to get the syntax just right. Can someone help here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this

```
var str = $('<div/>', {
    text:'Hello',
    class:'dimsdiv',
    id:'dim_src',
    style:'cursor:pointer',
    mouseenter:function(){ ... },
    mouseleave:function(){ ... }
});
$('#fpdiv').append(str);
```

Also remove the `.` from `dim.src`, instead use `dim_src` as `id`,  it's used as `class` selector in jQuery, not sure why you used it tho but `$('#'+dim.src)` is invalid.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mGNt5/1/).

Comment: Thanks. I used the . because I am reading form a JSON array. Easy enough to assign it to a variable first. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I still can;t get this format to work with multiple styles. Any ideas? I have several styles to set. I suppose I could append a .css() to the end. I'll try that.

Comment: [This is with multiple styles](http://jsbin.com/ahosar/1/edit) or [with css method too](http://jsbin.com/ahosar/4/edit).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [delegated-events approach](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and bind hover events (i.e. `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`) for dynamically created elements with class *"dimsdiv"* and parent element with ID *"fpdiv"*:

```
$("#fpdiv").on({
    mouseenter : function() {
        // hover on
    },
    mouseleave : function() {
        // hover off
    }
}, ".dimsdiv");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.on('hover','  has been deprecated in the latest jQuery version..
```

You need to use delegated events to do that.. Add the events to the parent container .

The second approach is to add the events once the element is created

```
$(function() {
    var addEvent = function() {
        $('.dimsdiv').unbind().hover(function {}, function {});
    }

        // Lets say you are creating your div's here
        $('#btn').on('click', function() {
           // Create Div
             var str = '<div class="dimsdiv" id="'+dim.src+'" cursor:pointer;"></div>'; 
             $('#fpdiv').append(str);

            // Call the function here
            addEvent();

        });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

The shorthand `hover` alias for `on` was removed in 1.8. You can use the `hover()` method instead. It accepts one or two functions as arguments to handle the hover-in and hover-out events.

```
$('#'+dim.src).hover(
  function () {
    // hover in code here
  },
  function () {
   // hover out code here
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a live function so you can set it once and it will affect your dynamic html.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: `live()` is deprecated. Consider using `on()` instead.