# Jquery On not working in IE9

Tags: jquery

The following code works fine in all my CSS3 browsers except for IE9. Does anyone have an idea why? I have several divs of class dismdiv set up in big div with ID fpdiv. I should get alert boxes on enter and exit of each of my dimsdiv areas. But not in IE9 for some reason.

Thanks, in advance!

```
this.setDimsRoll = function() {
    $("#fpdiv").on({
        mouseenter : function() {
            alert("on")
        },
        mouseleave : function() {
            alert("off");
        }
    }, ".dimsdiv");
}
```

Some clarification. This is a method in a javascript 'class' thus, the 'this'. You can ignore that part. This gets called after the dimsdivs are created dynamically. That's why I opted for this method as a reslt of my other post:

[Jquery - How to I add an event after dynamic create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648195/jquery-how-to-i-add-an-event-after-dynamic-create)

Normally, I would just use hover or something else, but this was required to handle the dynamic objects.

Comment: I don't immediately see anything wrong. Are you using jQuery 1.8.0?

Comment: Are you actually calling setDimsRoll somewhere?

Comment: Also, forgive my ignorance on this, but what is the purpose of ", ".dimsdiv");"

Comment: And what is "this" in this instance? Some more code around this would probably clear up most of our questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to fill the div with a clear pixel. Turns out that empty divs don't detect on IE. Thanks Microsoft!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you should be binding to document object's event seeing as the elements are dynamically created. Something along the lines of:

```
this.setDimsRoll = function() {
    $(document).on({ 
        mouseenter: function () { 
            alert("on")
        }, 

        mouseleave: function () { 
            alert("off")
        } 
    }, '.dimsdiv');
}
```

Also on a side note your contexts seem slighly mixed up. Which element are you actually trying to bind the mouse events to `.dimsdiv` or `#fpdiv`?

Comment: This is a standard method Zappa -- as in the reference I provided. The methodology is sound, from a jquery standpoint. It works fine in all versions of Firefox, Safari and Chrome I can test it in. it is only IE that is troubling me. The entire thing is already bound to (document). I only provided a snippet for clarity. I was wondring if someone knew of weirdness in IE (other than the fact that IE continues to suck, even to this day) that might provide a work around.

Comment: TO answer your question, #fpdiv exists and dimsdiv elements are added using $('#fpdiv').append() commands. Then I need to add the mouse over controls to them.